# Can't run gparted in fresh system

Tags: 14.04, gparted

Trying to run gparted in fresh installed Ubuntu. System not found this program. When I try to install I have report that it is already installed. How to solve this problem?

```
g@g-Lenovo:~$ gparted
The program 'gparted' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install gparted
g@g-Lenovo:~$ sudo aptitude install gparted
[sudo] password for g: 
gparted is already installed at the requested version (0.25.0-1)
gparted is already installed at the requested version (0.25.0-1)
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 130 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Comment: Have you tried `which gparted` ?

Comment: `gparted` is a graphical program and it needs elevated permissions. Run it from Dash or from a terminal window with `gksudo gparted` or `sudo -H gparted`. Never run a graphical program with 'plain sudo' because it might damage your user's configuration files.

Comment: `which gparted` brings nothing

Comment: `sudo -H gparted` brings `gparted: command not found`

Answer (score 6):

This is caused by a bug in the installer where it removes certain packages from the target system that are installed in the live environment, but does so only by deleting the files rather than removing the package.  Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gparted` to force the package to be reinstalled even though the system thinks it already is.  IIRC, you will need to do the same for the libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a package that gparted depends on.